# How i can get child value using condition (FIREBASE & SDK)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

What I want to do for my Login page is log as user using email/password and when "role" is equal to flood victim (the other role is Rescuer and Admin). The Flood victim page is HomeActivity.class and the rescuer page is HomeRes.class.

Here is my code for loginActivity:

LoginAcitivty:

```
  mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPswd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
         //Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successfull!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("User");

       //check if user has success registered

      reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEmail).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()  {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          Log.d("User exists", "Welcome!");
           String value =  snapshot.child("userRole").getValue().toString();

            if (value.equals("Flood Victim") && value != null) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                      finish();
           } else if (value.equals("Rescuer")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, homeRescuer.class));
                      finish();
                  } else {
                  startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, homeFv.class));
                         finish();
                    }
                 }
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
        });

}else {
   // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
      Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
 }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Database User]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` needs to handle this list by looping over the children of the snapshot it gets.

```
reference.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userEmail).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()  {

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) { // 
       String value = userSnapshot.child("userRole").getValue(String.class); //  

        if ("Flood Victim".equals(value)) { // 
          startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
          finish();
       } else if ("Rescuer".equals(value)) { //  
         startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, homeRescuer.class));
         finish();
       } else {
         startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, homeFv.class));
         finish();
       }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException(); //  never ignore errors
  }
});
```